# Jinja2 substring integer

Tags: python, substring, jinja2

I have a question and I tried to solve diff way with Jinja2. I have a number that is saved in database. When I print the original number is for ex: **907333-5000**. I want that number to be printed in this format: **(907) 333-5000** but I don't know exactly how to do with Jinja2. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that the number is stored as a string in your db.

The you could do -

```
{% print "("+num[:3]+") "+num[3:] %}
```

where you want to print the phone number.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can create a filter for phonenumbers like {{ phone_number|phone }}